# How do I run unit tests for a catkin package?

Tags: ros, unit-testing

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [camera_info_manager](http://ros.org/wiki/camera_info_manager) package was converted to catkin, but I suspect an error: **rostest** is listed as a `<build_depend>` and a `<run_depend>`, rather than a `<test_depend>`.

I checked out an **image_common** catkin workspace using **wstool**. I can build those packages with **catkin_make**, but have not been able to figure out how to run the **camera_info_manager** unit tests.

I tried `make test` in every directory I could think of:

```
$ make test
make: *** No rule to make target `test'.  Stop.
```

Google has not revealed any answers. So, how is this done, now?

EDIT: I noticed that `<test_depend>gtest</test_depend>` was missing and added it. Still not running.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54051/how-do-i-run-unit-tests-for-a-catkin-package?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the make targets are:

- `make tests` to build them
- `make run_test*` for each test (you can tab complete the targets)
- `make run_tests` runs all tests

See:

- hydro: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/run_tests.html
- indigo: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/run_tests.html

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-02**:
Thanks, William. That's what I needed.